# Invoke a main method of a jar in zeppelinUI (spark-submit)

Tags: apache-spark, hortonworks-data-platform, apache-zeppelin

I have a main method "myMain" in the  "myJar.jar"(I loaded this dependency in the spark-interpreter of Zeppelin UI). I have set all other spark configurations in the spark interpreter.

Now I want to submit a spark-submit job with parameters that are requiring by myMain class in Zeppelin UI.

something like(in zeppelin UI)(assume my class takes -i,-o,-c parameters):
--class myMain myJar.jar -i input -o output -c configFile

Comment: Hi, I'v just read [spark interpreter documentation](https://zeppelin.apache.org/docs/latest/interpreter/spark.html), I cound't find the way to submit spark jars in UI. You can use `conf/zeppelin-env.sh` to set `SPARK_SUBMIT_OPTIONS`

Comment: Yeah. I am okay setting " --class myMain myJar.jar -i input -o output -c configFile" in SPARK_SUBMIT_OPTIONS. But how to kick start this spark-submit the job from UI?

Comment: If you run spark interpreter, Zeppelin will execute your spark-submit job. For example, `%spark println(1)`.

Comment: To be precise, If you run spark interpreter without spark submit option, Zeppelin will execute `RemoteInterpreterServer`. But if you set `SPARK_SUBMIT_OPTIONS` in `zeppelin-env.sh`, Zeppelin will launch `SparkSubmit` process. You can check by executing `jps` command in terminal.

Answer (score 0):

I'v just read [spark interpreter documentation](https://zeppelin.apache.org/docs/latest/interpreter/spark.html), But i could't find the way to submit spark jars in UI.

Instead of, you can use `SPARK_SUBMIT_OPTIONS` in `conf/zeppelin-env.sh`

### More Details

- If you run spark interpreter without spark submit option, Zeppelin will execute `RemoteInterpreterServer` which including local spark.
- But if you set `SPARK_SUBMIT_OPTIONS` in `zeppelin-env.sh`, Zeppelin will launch `SparkSubmit` process.

You can check by executing `jps` command in terminal.

```
99212 RemoteInterpreterServer
96926 ZeppelinServer
```